# Django Query same week last year

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to compare sums of events in the same week (isocalendar), year over year.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTime(...
    hits = models.IntegerField(...
```

I've got this sorted for last year, last month, same month last year, same day last year using variations on:

```
same_month_last_year = MyModel.objects.filter(date__month = (datetime.datetime.now().month), date__year = (datetime.datetime.now() - relativedelta(years = 1)).year).aggregate(total=Sum('hits')['total']
```

I don't see an equivalent 'week' function. I can use .isocalendar()[1] on the right side of the equation but that's of no help on the left. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django 1.11 added a [week filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#week). Can you use that?

If not, you might be able to look at the source code and cherry pick it.

As a last resort, you could use Python to calculate the date range for the same week last year, then pass those dates as filters to the Django query.

Comment: Perfect solution.